# Long term usage of loperamide to treat IBS

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, irritable-bowel-syndrome, diarrhea, otc-over-the-counter

Is loperamide safe to use long term for the treatment of chronic diarrhea in IBS patients?

Answer (score 2):

### Safety of Loperamide

Loperamide ([anti-diarrhoea medication such as Dioraleze or Imodium](https://beta.nhs.uk/medicines/loperamide)) is often the go-to treatment for diarrhoea.  As the medication only acts on the digestive tract, there appears to be little risk associated with long-term or frequent use of Loperamide, and the medication is considered to be a [relatively safe, well-tolerated option for dealing with diarrhoea.](https://www.verywellhealth.com/how-safe-is-imodium-1945154)

There are precautions to be followed however, if you take them long term **and/or suffer from inflammatory bowel disease (IBD)**.

A prescription is required for

- a child under 12 years old
- a child aged 12 to 17 years old with IBS or long lasting diarrhoea
- an adult aged 18 years and older with long lasting diarrhoea

### Precautions

[Amongst other precautions](https://beta.nhs.uk/medicines/loperamide),

- Do not take any more Loperamide and drink plenty of water if you become [constipated](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/constipation).  If you are told to take Loperamide long-term, wait for the constipation to go before taking more.
- Do not take more than the recommended amount. Too much loperamide can cause serious heart problems (including a fast or irregular heartbeat).
- You must never take Loperamide for more than 48 hours [without seeking advice from your doctor or gastroenterologist.](https://beta.nhs.uk/medicines/loperamide)
- Seek medical advice if you have blood in your poo and/or a temperature (more than 38°C).

### People who suffer from IBD

**[This is different to IBS](http://patients.gi.org/topics/inflammatory-bowel-disease/#tabs2)**

You should not take Loperamide without permission from your doctor. The use of anti-diarrhea medications such as Imodium places IBD patients at risk for the development of [toxic megacolon](http://aia5.adam.com/content.aspx?productId=117&pid=1&gid=000248), a potentially life-threatening disorder.

### Sources

[A.D.A.M.: "Toxic Megacolon."](http://aia5.adam.com/content.aspx?productId=117&pid=1&gid=000248)

[American College of Gastroenterology : "IBD."](http://patients.gi.org/topics/inflammatory-bowel-disease/#tabs2)

[NHS : "Imodium (Loperamide)](https://beta.nhs.uk/medicines/loperamide)"

[VeryWell Health: "Imodium (Loperamide)"](https://www.verywellhealth.com/how-safe-is-imodium-1945154)

Comment: The question is about IBS. Did you intentionally answered about IBD?

Comment: Yes @Jan.  I mentioned IBD because there is specific risk with this condition.  The general safety and risks is associated with IBS and other conditions